# django url dispatcher with HTTP GET arguments

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

In a urls.py file:

```
url(r'^api/user_info/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z\d]+)\&', 'corresponding.view')
url(r'^api/user_info/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z\d]+)', 'corresponding.view')
```

There will always be HTTP Get arguments to `/api/user_info/username`.

The problem is that in the `corresponding.view` function, `username` will evaluate to something like "myusername?clientversion=2.0", instead of it evaluating to "myusername" and `request.GET['clientversion'] = "2.0"`.

The first `url` call is to try to catch the ampersand in there, but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079476/django-urls-using-a-in-the-url); you don't access query parameters using Django's URLConf. Trying to process `?` or `&` characters using the URL resolver will not lead to happiness.

Just use the following URL pattern:

```
url(r'^api/user_info/(?P<username>\w\+)/$', 'corresponding.view')
```

and access the `clientversion` query parameter in your `corresponding.view()` function:

```
def view(request):
    client_version = request.GET.get('clientversion')
    ...
```

Or, if you're saying it should be *mandatory*,

```
from django.http import Http404

def view(request):
    try:
        client_version = request.GET['clientversion']
    except KeyError:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Your response was very enlightening for me. Thank you. However I realized that my true problem was pure stupidity on my end: My client software was requesting the page with the HTTP GET parameters starting with '&' rather than '?'... Took me several hours before I noticed... just one of those days...