# Django 1.10 - url ending with ? can't be retrieved at view

Tags: regex, django

I have an url like -

```
...poll/3/what's-up?
```

In `urlpatterns`, I am checking for any kind of string for question text with following code -

```
url(r'^poll/(?P<question_id>[0-9])/(?P<question_text>.+)', views.question_details),
```

After debugging i see it returns in view -

`question_text = what's-up`

but not

`question_text = what's-up?`

I think this is my `regex` implementation issue.

Comment: The elements after the `?` are not part of the url, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12079541/5288316).

Comment: yes, query parameters are executed after `?`. What I have tried to verify the question text with record. I think I have to skip `?` in both url `request.GET` and record text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape `?` in your Regex, and see if that helps:

```
url(r'^poll/(?P<question_id>[0-9])/(?P<question_text>.+\??)', views.question_details),
```